# Display issue with Huion tablet

Tags: drawing-tablet

I have been using a Huion tablet tablet. I have 2 monitors connected to my macbook. At first, my tablet automatically worked on whichever display that my cruiser was at, i.e., if I'm working on display 1, all the tablet area was display 1, then if I moved cruiser to display 2, all area of tablet was corresponding two display 2. In this mode, I was not able to move from one display to the other using stylus, it stoped at the edge of the display and I should have moved it by the mouse. But now, suddenly, I can either choose display 1, display 2, or both together. The problem is, when I choose both together, half of table is for one display and the other half is for the other display. I was wondering how to go back to the mode where tablet automatically worked on the whole area of the display on which my cruiser is located at.

Comment: Please contact the hardware manufacture for support regarding their products.

Comment: @Scott Thanks for the comment, but they didn't respond after 10 days.

Comment: We can't troubleshoot hardware issues here. It's not within scope and is off topic.

Comment: @Scott OK, Got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One shortcut is to use programmable tablet keys to define display switch. This just moves between two displays without hassle, but inherently is different than what I was looking for.
[image]